# Unable to find the common ratio.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am asked to,

A GP with first term $2$ has for sum of first three terms $14$. I have to find the common ratio $r$ given it is positive.

I reached,

$\cfrac{2(r^3-1)}{(r-1)}=14$

$\cfrac{(r^3-1)}{(r-1)}=7$

$r^3-1=7r-7$

I am unable to progress further.

Comment: An alternative view: $2+2r+?=14{}{}$.

Comment: @user361970, welcome to SE. You can accept any answer http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: You may get answer very easily if you try some easy method .but if you want to solve the equation in 3rd degree you may use Synthetic division and long division @user361970

Answer (score 2):

A geometric progression means that to get to the next term you multiply by a constant which we call the common ratio $r \neq 0$ each time. So the first three terms are:

$$2,2r,2r^2$$

It is given to us that they add to $14$:

$$2r^2+2r+2=14$$

But remember it is given to us that $r>0$.

If your going to do it your way note that:

$$(r^3-1)=(r-1)(r^2+r+1)$$

This can be found by noting $r=1$ is a root of $r^3-1$ and then applying long division or synthetic division.

Comment: Thanks this was actually easy

Comment: (+1) Provided that $r\ne1$. But it's easy to see that $r$ can't take $1$, because the sum would be $2\times3$ instead of $14$.

Comment: You're welcome @user361970

Answer (score 2):

$7 = \cfrac{(r^3-1)}{(r-1)} = r^2 + r + 1$

.................

Answer (score 2):

$r^3-1=7r-7$

$\implies  r^3-7r=1-7$

$\implies  r(r^2-7)=-6$

$\implies  r(r^2-7)=2\times-3$

$\implies r=2$

Answer (score 0):

The first term a=2(given),and let $r$ be common  ratio.
sum of first three term in G.p (S)= $a+ar+ar^2$
$$a+ar+ar^2=14$$
$$2+2r+2r^2=14$$
$$1+r+r^2=7$$
Now we get a quadric equation .well,solve it.
The factors of equation are $(x+3)(x-2)=0$
You need positive solution ....then the solution(root) is 2 .